# Can I use distance covariance for similarity measure in manifold learning?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, kernel-trick, similarities, manifold-learning, distance-covariance

In manifold learning such as Laplacian Eigenmap, a common method of obtaining the similarity matrix (that measures "affinity" or "connectivity") is to use Gaussian kernel in terms of the data points' Euclidean distances.

Question = can I use distance covariance or distance correlation instead of Euclidean distances?

(I suppose why not since distance covariance is positivity preserving and symmetric)

Answer (score 1):

Distance covariance (or distance correlation) is a correlational metric.  Basically, it takes as input two distance matrices and outputs a scalar (the distance covariance).  If the distance covariance is much greater than 0 (test significance with many random permutations), then there is a relationship between the two random vectors.

So note that distance covariance does not give a kernel or similarity matrix that methods such as MDS or Laplacian Eigenmap use to perform dimensionality reduction.  However, it has been used for linear dimensionality reductions that identify linear and nonlinear relationships between sets of variables (see http://proceedings.mlr.press/v54/cowley17a/cowley17a.pdf and https://stat.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/Wenhui%20Sheng_IWSM%202013.pdf).

Comment: `does not give a kernel or similarity matrix that methods such as MDS or Laplacian Eigenmap use to perform dimensionality reduction` Can you unwrap it? Why? What matrix they give which a matrix of distance correlations cannot be?

Comment: Distance covariance is a scalar.  It does not yield a matrix.